# DevExpress XtraGrid : What is the proper way to obtain the RowHandle from an Object

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am listing a collection of date ranges (each date range is represented by a *Period* object) in a DevExpress **XtraGrid** (WinForms).

In a method which splits a Period in two (the split date is entered by the user), the code does this :

1. Obtains a Period reference on the focused row. ((Period)GridViewPeriods.GetRow(selectedRows[0]);)
2. Clones the selected period.
3. Obtains a reference on the newly cloned Period.

After the job is done, I want to put the focus on the newly cloned Period. At this point, I only have my two Period references.

I haven't found any method in the XtraGrid that could locate a row based on it's value (like returning a RowHandle by passing an object).

I ended up writing this helper method :

```
    public int GetDataRowIndex(RatePeriod period)
    {
        int foundIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewRatePeriods.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            if ((RatePeriod)GridViewRatePeriods.GetRow(i) == period)
            {
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundIndex;
    }
```

Then I set the focus on the newly created Period like this :

```
GridViewPeriods.FocusedRowHandle = GetDataRowIndex(tailingPeriod);
```

Is there any shorter or smarter way to do that ?

Comment: your data doesn't happen to have unique identifier in it that is shown in the grid does it ?

Comment: what if you added a column that did have unique identifing info and used the LocateByValue (See my edited answer)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want to avoid doing that, also. I don't like having to put that kind of data in the UI just to be able to retreive a specific row. Seems to "hackerish" to me.

Comment: Can we see some code on how you are adding the cloned row? AddNewRow should set focus to the new record.

Comment: The grid is bound to a datasource, which is a List of Period objects. I'm adding the newly cloned Period object to the collection.

Comment: If your datasource supports the IBindingList interface the AddNewRow should work.

Comment: Check out this DX doc http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it the best way though it seems like you are having to go through a bunch of stuff to get what you are looking for Dev Express has the same solution as you have

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1488.aspx

I thought maybe the rowindex could be related back to the order of your datasource but there does not appear to any collation

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1488.aspx

If you are displaying any kinda unique identifying infomation in a single cell you might be able to use  [LocateByValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_LocateByValuetopic) if you were not displaying the unique identifying infomation you could always hide that column

Comment: Thanks for your input. The referenced post is quite old, but, as I see it was updated recently, I assume there is no better way to get it done.

Comment: @SteveHémond are you displaying any kinda unique identifying infomation ? you might be able to use http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_LocateByValuetopic

Comment: No I am not. The reason of my post is also because I want to avoid doing hidden column value tweaking stuff.